# How to add whitespace after every item in a list in ConTeXt?

Tags: spacing, lists, context, enumerate, context-mkiv

I have a document containing some questions. I need to leave readers space to write a few sentences as an answer.

I am using this code:

```
\startitemize[r]
    \item Where do most bears live?
    \item What kind of bears live in your area? When have you seen them?
    \item If you meet a bear, what should you do?
\stopitemize
```

With the grid on, this leaves only one empty line after each item, e.g.:

```
i. Where do most bears live?

ii. What kind of bears live in your area? When have you seen them?

iii. If you meet a bear, what should you do?

This is some other text.
```

How can I add 1 or 2 extra empty lines after each item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define a new `itemgroup` for questions, and set the `inbetween` and `after` keys to specify an appropriate blank space:

```
\defineitemgroup
  [questions]
  [inbetween={\blank[2*line]},
   after={\blank[2*line]},
   symbol=r]


\starttext
\input knuth
\startquestions
  \item Where do most bears live?
  \item What kind of bears live in your area? When have you seen them?
  \item If you meet a bear, what should you do?
\stopquestions
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

This way, your regular items are not changed.

Answer (score 2):

```
\starttext
\setupblank[4*big]
\startitemize[r]
    \item Where do most bears live?
    \item What kind of bears live in your area? When have you seen them?
    \item If you meet a bear, what should you do?
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```